# Add style to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I got this code from a [website](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/HTML5-Show-Display-multiple-image-preview-before-upload-with-FileUpload-control-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx) and applied to my code:

```js
window.onload = function () {
      var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileupload");
      fileUpload.onchange = function () {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
          var dvPreview = document.getElementById("dvpreview");
          dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
          var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png)$/;
          for (var i = 0; i < fileUpload.files.length; i++) {
            var file = fileUpload.files[i];
            if (regex.test(file.name.toLowerCase())) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function (e) {
                var img = document.createElement("IMG");
                img.width="300";
                img.height ="300";
                img.src = e.target.result;
                dvPreview.appendChild(img);
              }
              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
              alert(file.name + " is not a valid image file.");
              dvPreview.innerHTML = "";
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

It works properly, but I want some more style to be added to my code. Specially the padding and the object-fit css properties.

I tried to run:

```js
 img.objectFit="cover";
 img.style.objectFit="cover";
 img.css("object-fit","cover");
```

and a lot more possibilities that i could search and apply, but any of those worked out.

What is the right way to make this work?

Comment: `img.style.padding = "10px";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.width = '300';
img.height = '300';
img.style.padding = '20px';
img.style.objectFit = 'fill';
document.body.appendChild(img);
```